# A movie in which an alien with human form crashes and rebuilds his ship with a love story in between

Tags: story-identification

I can't put a name on a movie from the 80s or 90s.

The alien is a nice-looking guy who has to reinvent most of the technology he needs to rebuild his spaceship.

There's a scene when he feels dizzy inside an elevator, like a spaceman apparently.

Well, I can't remember much of it, but there's also a love story in the movie.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218156/audio-book-novel-about-a-human-like-alien-who-comes-to-earth-and-loves-gin (about the novel on which the movie was based)

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [The Man Who Fell to Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074851/).

The lead character ([Thomas Jerome Newton, played by David Bowie](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0024240/)) is feeling dizzy in the elevator because he wasn't used to the higher gravity on Earth (relative to his home world), which effects got worse when going up in a fast elevator.

Summary from IMDB:

> Thomas Jerome Newton is a humanoid alien who comes to Earth to get water for his dying planet. He starts a high technology company to get the billions of dollars he needs to build a return spacecraft, and meets Mary-Lou, a girl who falls in love with him. He does not count on the greed and ruthlessness of business here on Earth, however.

Answer (score 5):

It actually is The man who fell to Earth, but not the David Bowie version from 1976. The one I saw was from 1987, a TV remake with Lewis Smith ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093486/)).

Thanks a lot for your help. I'll watch both now, for memories and movie comparison. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Fell_to_Earth_%28TV_program%29) tells more about the differences between the movies and the novel, written by Walter Tevis in 1963.

Comment: If you found the correct answer please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it "The man who fell to earth" featuring David Bowie?

Comment: No, David Bowie was not playing in it. The guy was alone in his ship, all the story took place on earth.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can think of.

Comment: The "orange means go fast" is from Starman, with Jeff Bridges, not The Man Who Fell To Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be Starman. 1984 film directed by John Carpenter, starring Jeff Bridges and Karen Allen.

Comment: This was my first guess too, but I don't remember the part about the elevator...