# 80's sci-fi B movie where an alien, disguised as a human, crash lands in a desert

Tags: story-identification, tv, b-movies

I was a kid and saw this film on TV in the 80's.

It starts with a crashed ship somewhere in the desert. There is a man who's an alien but I don't remember the plot... I think he just wants to go home...?

He meets a woman and reveals that he's not from Earth and take off his "disguise", still looking quite human but with strange eyes and no hair...

It is definitely not *Starman*, it was cheap, made for TV.

edit:

I checked The Man Who Fell to Earth... It could be but I don't think that's the one, there are pictures of other alien kids on the youtube link provided and if I remember correctly the man was the only alien in that film.

maybe a tv show pilot not picked up like anihilator, something like that...?

Comment: You have a decent description here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Comment: Did he come to Earth for water?

Comment: I would have sworn that there was a recent story ID question with the same premise, but I can't find it...

Comment: No hair with odd eyes reminds me of The Man Who Fell to Earth.  https://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/17239/looking-back-at-nicolas-roeg%E2%80%99s-the-man-who-fell-to-earth

Comment: @DoscoJones me too, but I can't recall any details.

Comment: The crashed ship in the desert and alien(s) disguised as humans reminds of It Came From Outer Space (1953), but the aliens were far more alien looking than you describe.

Comment: @DoscoJones hence why I asked if he came for our water.

Comment: "He meets a woman and reveals that he's not from Earth and take off his "disguise", still looking quite human but with strange eyes and no hair..." - remember this scene. Oh, no, I'm thinking of Cocoon, sorry.

Comment: possibly the same as the 1987 made-for-TV movie mentioned at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28075/a-movie-in-which-an-alien-with-human-form-crashes-and-rebuilds-his-ship-with-a-l

Answer (score 1):

[*The Man Who Fell to Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Fell_to_Earth) (1976), based (loosely) on the book of the same name.

> Thomas Jerome Newton is a humanoid alien who comes to Earth from a distant planet on a mission to take water back to his home planet, which is experiencing a catastrophic drought. Throughout the film are brief sequences of his wife and children back on his home planet, suffering, perhaps dying.

Comment: I've added a brief summary from Wikipedia that matches some of the OP's description but could you [edit] to explain how this matches?

Comment: https://youtu.be/zfQd2LlJ_Rs. This shows all the points mentioned.

Comment: if the video is helpful to your answer you should [edit] it in and also explain some of what the video shows in case it gets taken down. Note, if you paste a YouTube link directly into your post it will onebox.

Comment: You guys. I don't know if you're admins or what, but you're more bothered with bureaucracy than simply answering questions. Every poster is badgered with lists of "do this", "do that". It's just a Q&A site, not a legal document. Take the answer or not. Up to you.

Comment: I won't keep "badgering" you but just to answer a couple of points, no most people who "badger" users are just regular users not admins. The reason users like me "badger" people is because answers are supposed to be self contained and explain the whys/hows and be of higher quality than a single line comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely [*Starman*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088172/), made in 1984, starring Jeff Bridges and Karen Allen.

> An alien takes the form of a young widow's husband and asks her to drive him from Wisconsin to Arizona. The government tries to stop them.

[image: Starman poster]

Comment: Could you edit to explain why this is correct and how it matches?

Comment: It doesn't sound like this at all. There was no crashed ship in the desert in Starman,  and he didn't take off any disguise.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - True - but this is the first thing I thought of, as well. And, with Arizona as a destination, the desert could factor into the memory,